# Function to alternate players' turns, unless a player has won

Tags: javascript

I am doing a coding challenge and it basically says this. There are two players, "black" and "white" and they take turns at a game. If a player won the last turn then it is his turn again, otherwise it is the other player's turn. The whole challenge is [here](https://www.codewars.com/kata/simple-fun-number-261-whose-move/train/javascript).

Here is the original code I used for that:

```
function whoseMove(lastPlayer, win) {
  if (lastPlayer == "white") {
      if (win) {
          return "white";
      }
      return "black";
  } else {
      if (win) {
          return "black";
      }
      return "white";
  }
}
```

however I realised that this could be simplified by changing it to this:

```
function whoseMove(lastPlayer, win) {
  if (lastPlayer == "white") {
      return win ? "white" : "black";
  } else {
      return win ? "black" : "white";
  }
}
```

I wonder if this could be simplified even more? Is it possible to have more than one condition in the conditional return statement (I think that is what it is called)?

Comment: Please also show us the code that calls this function. I suspect that you would be better off putting the conditional elsewhere in your code, instead of in this function that appears to give the winning player an extra turn.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"White" is returned when both conditions are true or when both are false so you can use XOR, denoted as `^` in JavaScript.

```
function whoseMove(lastPlayer, win) {
  return lastPlayer == "white" ^ !!win ? "black" : "white";
}
```

I would advise against it since that's less obvious. Here's a self-explanatory condition:

```
function whoseMove(lastPlayer, win) {
  return lastPlayer == "white" && win || lastPlayer != "white" && !win ? "white" : "black";
}
```

Comment: Personally, I would much prefer the OP's original code to either of these solutions. There is way too much happening on a single line even in your second function here.

Answer (score 3):

You could return the same player if win is true, otherwise return the other player, this is done with only 2 tests:

```
function whoseMove(lastPlayer, win) {
    if (win) return lastPlayer;
    return lastPlayer == "black" ? "white" : "black";
}
```

Comment: Yup, this was my first thought when I saw the question. I find this so much clearer than using XOR here.